# Version Control for SQL Server Stored Procs/Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

As a C# programmer, I am familiar with using TFS for version control.  However, I am doing some database work, for example, triggers that I don't want to get lost.  What is best practice for this?  Right now, I just do backups of the entire database (5 gigs) but that seems an overkill as I really only want the structure/triggers etc.

In searching around, it appears there is a Plug in for SSMS for TFS 2010. Is anyone actually using this?  What is typical for dba's on this subject?

Update

It just occurred to me the simplest and easiest way to achieve this is just add a folder to my existing project called SQL, and then add a *.sql file to it.  This is then checked into TFS just like any other file in the project.  By clicking it to open in VS, it opens up the new Database Tools windows so you can run the SQL and see the results in the pane below.

Second Update:

After using Sql Server Projects in Visual Studio for the past few days, I have come to really like them.  It's a lot different from using SSMS, but once I got my head around the concepts, it works very well.  And the main point is that you end up with a complete set of scripts for you database which are then very easy to keep in source control.

Greg

Comment: A Visual Studio database project maybe?  That would use TFS just like anything else.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2012 there is a nice type of db project that can import database objects in solution( i don't remember the name but i can try it again if you really needed). Also you can use third party like Redgate solution for version control.

Comment: OK, am checking out Database projects now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used it for a short period of time, and had a good experience working with it in general. But it depends on what you expect from it. You have much more sophisticated tools like [redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/) that enables you to work native in your database environment and keeps your database in sync with the repository.

The SSMS plugin will make you have to work and double check sometimes manually to see that you checked-in everything you executed.

for more information you can look at:
http://blog.discountasp.net/using-team-foundation-server-2010-source-control-from-sql-server-management-studio/

http://www.techtree.co.uk/sql-server/management-studio-ssms/use-team-foundation-server-tfs-as-your-source-control-in-ssms/

Answer (score 2):

[Versioning a database directly from SSMS](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_source_control.aspx), can be done with ApexSQL Source Control. You do not have to script objects, in your case triggers, and then send them to the repository. This add-in supports TFS natively, so after you [link a database and initial commit database objects](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/getting-a-database-under-version-control-how-to-link-a-database-to-source-control-and-initially-commit-objects/) all changes will be tracked in the real time. Whenever you change object, the change will be shown in the Action center tab and change will be marked. So, you can see what is changed since the last time you sent version of that object to the repository.

With this add-in you can revert every change made from the moment you linked your database to the repository.
Working with this SSMS add-in shorten time spend on checking all made changes, since it is working for you.